# How to properly escape single and double quotes

Tags: python, lxml

I have a lxml etree HTMLParser object that I'm trying to build xpaths with to assert xpaths, attributes of the xpath and text of that tag.  I ran into a problem when the text of the tag has either single-quotes(') or double-quotes(") and I've exhausted all my options.

Here's a sample object I created

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(StringIO(<html><body><p align="center">Here is my 'test' "string"</p></body></html>), parser)
```

Here is the snippet of code and then different variations of the variable being read in

```
   def getXpath(self)
     xpath += 'starts-with(., \'' + self.text + '\') and '
     xpath += ('count(@*)=' + str(attrsCount) if self.exactMatch else "1=1") + ']'
```

self.text is basically the expected text of the tag, in this case: Here is my 'test' "string"

this fails when i try to use the xpath method of the HTMLParser object

```
tree.xpath(self.getXpath())
```

Reason is because the xpath that it gets is this '/html/body/p[starts-with(.,'Here is my 'test' "string"') and 1=1]'

How can I properly escape the single and double quotes from the self.text variable?  I've tried triple quoting, wrapping self.text in repr(), or doing a re.sub or string.replace escaping ' and " with \' and \"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what we can see [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) and [w3 school](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp), you should not have `'` and `"` in nodes content, even if only `<` and `&` are said to be stricly illegal. They should be replaced by corresponding "predefined entity references", that are `&apos;` and `&quot;`.

By the way, the Python parsers I use will take care of this transparently: when writing, they are replaced; when reading, they are converted.

After a second reading of your answer, I tested some stuff with the `'` and so on in Python interpreter. And it will escape everything for you!

```
>>> 'text {0}'.format('blabla "some" bla')
'text blabla "some" bla'
>>> 'ntsnts {0}'.format("ontsi'tns")
"ntsnts ontsi'tns"
>>> 'ntsnts {0}'.format("ontsi'tn' \"ntsis")
'ntsnts ontsi\'tn\' "ntsis'
```

So we can see that Python escapes things correctly. Could you then copy-paste the error message you get (if any)?

Comment: I see, the error I'm getting is from lxml: XPathEvalError: Invalid expression, stack trace is
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2029, in lxml.etree._ElementTree.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:45934)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 379, in lxml.etree.XPathDocumentEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:114389)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 242, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:113063)
  File "xpath.pxi", line 228, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._raise_eval_error (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:112935)

Comment: mmh, error is raised by `lxml`, because expression is said to be invalid. Could you please paste the value of `xpath`, when rendered by  `print`?

Comment: escaping the ' and " with their corresponding HTML entities did the trick.  I was really tired last night and wasn't thinking that the string was actually HTML being parsed.  Thanks for providing this guidance

Comment: Great, so that's what I thought: `lxml` is not really happy when these characters are used directly in content. You're welcome - please do not forget to accept the answer!

Comment: Issue is i had to abandon this because it was causing a lot of headaches.  Later on I ran into a problem that href's with underscores could not return a valid xpath but only when writing a unit test, it worked fine in the python shell itself.  Also I was dealing with horrible HTML and I also found invalid chars in alt attributes.  So with a little trial and error I have things working but I removed the starts-with part of the xpath and asserting text of the tag separately

Answer (score 1):

there are more options to choose from, especially the `"""` and `'''` might be what you want.

```
s = "a string with a single ' quote"
s = 'a string with a double " quote'
s = """a string with a single ' and a double " quote"""
s = '''another string with those " quotes '.'''
s = r"raw strings let \ be \"
s = r'''and can be added \ to " any ' of """ those things'''
s = """The three-quote-forms
       may contain
       newlines."""
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is applicable If u r using python `lxml`.
Its better to leave the escaping for `lxml`. We can do this by using `lxml`variables.
Suppose We have `xpath` as below:

```
//tagname[text='some_text']`
```

If `some_text` has both single and double quotes, then it causes `"Invalid Predicate error"`.
Neither escaping work for me nor triple quotes. Because xml won't accept triple quotes.

Solution worked for me is `lxml` variables.

We convert the xpath as below:

```
//tagname[text = $var]
```

Then execute

```
find = etree.XPath(xpath)
```

Then evaluate these variable to its value

```
elements = find(root, {'var': text})
```

Comment: This is a lifesaver trick for lxml that I didn't know about. Thanks!