# SQL syntax error with python strings

Tags: python, sql, syntax, sqlite

I'm having the following error:

```
  File "sqldata/basetables/places.py", line 24, in update
    sqldata.objs.c.execute("UPDATE places SET name='%s', matrix='%s', bans='%s', pop='%s' WHERE name='%s'" % (place.name,place.matrix,place.bans,place.pop,name))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "bob": syntax error
```

Where I have:

```
>>> place.name
'room'
>>> place.matrix
[['bob', False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
>>> place.bans
[]
>>> place.pop
[]
>>> name
'room'
```

For some reason the single quotes around `bob` seem to be causing the error, since if I replace `'bob'` with `True` it works, but the single quotes around `room` do not cause any errors. What is the best approach to correct this? I can't replace `'bob'` with `bob`, since I want a string there, not an object.

---

I tried the suggestions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708152/how-to-escape-single-quotes-in-python-on-server-to-be-used-in-javascript-on-clie) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802418/how-to-properly-escape-single-and-double-quotes) but the string remains the same. I also tried replacing `'bob'` for `''bob''`, `u'''bob'''`, `"bob"`, `"'bob'"`, `"\'bob\'"`. It all gives syntax error.

Removing the single quotes from the SQL query gives:

```
  File "sqldata/basetables/places.py", line 24, in update
    sqldata.objs.c.execute("UPDATE places SET name=%s, matrix=%s, bans=%s, pop=%s WHERE name=%s" % (place.name,place.matrix,place.bans,place.pop,name))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log your SQL string before sending it to execute. You'll see it comes out something like this given the values for `matrix` in your post:

```
UPDATE places SET name='room', matrix='[['bob', False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]'
```

Now, clearly, `'[['bob'` is not a valid string: you open a single quote, then close it again after the open brackets, but then continue the string regardless. You can't fix this by changing the value you're passing in: you need to change the SQL string.

One (extremely bad) solution would be to use double quotes in the SQL string instead of single ones: then you would get:

```
"""UPDATE places SET name="room", matrix="[['bob', False, False]..."""
```

which is at least valid.

But you **should not** do this. You should use the templating that is provided in the Python DB API:

```
"UPDATE places SET name=?, matrix=?, bans=?, pop=? WHERE name=?", (place.name,place.matrix,place.bans,place.pop,name)
```

This gets the db driver itself to do the interpolation, and protects you against SQL injection. See http://bobby-tables.com/ for why this is important.

Comment: Thanks. Just a note: doing it the "correct" way gave `sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.` Which was fixed by using `unicode(place.matrix)` to convert it to Unicode.