# Understanding how to quote XML string in order to serialize using Python's ElementTree

Tags: python, string, elementtree

My specs:

1. Python 3.4.3
2. Windows 7
3. IDE is Jupyter Notebooks

What I have referenced:

1. [how-to-properly-escape-single-and-double-quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802418/how-to-properly-escape-single-and-double-quotes)
2. [python-escaping-strings-for-use-in-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546717/python-escaping-strings-for-use-in-xml)
3. [escaping-characters-in-a-xml-file-with-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972210/escaping-characters-in-a-xml-file-with-python)

Here is the data and script, respectively, below (I have tried variations on serializing Column 'E' using both Sax and ElementTree):

**Data**

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
"3","8","1","<Request TransactionID="3" RequestType="FOO"><InstitutionISO /><CallID>23</CallID><MemberID>12</MemberID><MemberPassword /><RequestData><AccountNumber>2</AccountNumber><AccountSuffix>85</AccountSuffix><AccountType>S</AccountType><MPIAcctType>Checking</MPIAcctType><TransactionCount>10</TransactionCount></RequestData></Request>","<Response TransactionID="2" RequestType="HoldInquiry"><ShareList>0000',0001,0070,</ShareList></Response>","1967-12-25 22:18:13.471000","2005-12-25 22:18:13.768000","2","70","0"
```

**Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*-  coding: utf-8 -*-
import os.path
import sys
import csv
from io import StringIO 
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XMLParser
import xml
import xml.sax
from xml.sax import ContentHandler

class MyHandler(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self._charBuffer = []
        self._result = []

    def _getCharacterData(self):
        data = ''.join(self._charBuffer).strip()
        self._charBuffer = []
        return data.strip() #remove strip() if whitespace is important

    def parse(self, f):
        xml.sax.parse(f, self)
        return self._result


    def characters(self, data):
        self._charBuffer.append(data)

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if name == 'Response':
            self._result.append({})

    def endElement(self, name):
        if not name == 'Response': self._result[-1][name] = self._getCharacterData()

def read_data(path):
    with open(path, 'rU', encoding='utf-8') as data:
        reader = csv.DictReader(data, delimiter =',', quotechar="'", skipinitialspace=True)
        for row in reader:
            yield row

if __name__ == "__main__":
    empty = ''
    Response = 'sample.csv'
    for idx, row in enumerate(read_data(Response)):
        if idx > 10: break
        data = row['E']
        print(data) # The before
        data = data[1:-1]
        data = ""'{}'"".format(data)
        print(data) # Sanity check 
#         data = '<Response TransactionID="2" RequestType="HoldInquiry"><ShareList>0000',0001,0070,</ShareList></Response>'
        try:
            root = ElementTree.XML(data)
#             print(root)
        except StopIteration:
            raise
            pass
#         xmlstring = StringIO(data)
#         print(xmlstring)
#         Handler = MyHandler().parse(xmlstring)
```

Specifically, due to the quoting in the CSV file (which is beyond my control), I have had to resort to slicing the string (line 51) and then formatting it (line 52).

However the print out from the above attempt is as follows:

```
"<Response TransactionID="2" RequestType="HoldInquiry"><ShareList>0000'
<Response TransactionID="2" RequestType="HoldInquiry"><ShareList>0000

  File "<string>", line unknown
ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 69
```

Interestingly - if I assign the variable "data" (as in line 54) I receive this:

```
  File "<ipython-input-80-7357c9272b92>", line 56
data = '<Response TransactionID="2" RequestType="HoldInquiry"><ShareList>0000',0001,0070,</ShareList></Response>'
                                                                                  ^ 
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

I seek feedback and information on how to address utilizing the most Pythonic means to do so. Ideally, is there a method that can leverage ElementTree. Thank you, in advance, for your feedback and guidance.

Comment: Please put the code *here*.  Do not link to it.  Also, FYI: the code `""'{}'""` is interpreted as `"" '{}' ""`, and the three separate strings are concatenated.  Since the first and last strings are both empty, they are effectively ignored, leaving you with `data = '{}'.format(data)`, or just `data = data`.

Comment: @Kevin I am about to include the code and data as per your request. Thank you for clarifying; how would you then format a string with single quotes?

Comment: `"'{}'".format(data)` will wrap `data` with single quotes.  If you *also* want to wrap it in double quotes, you will need to backslash escape them.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for clarifying for me. I assume to address the parse error I can also escape the single quote in the ShareList tag, as well with some form of backslash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that You have badly formatted (well, badly quoted) csv data.

If csv file is beyond Your control I suggest not using csv reader to read them,
instead - if You can rely on each field being properly quoted - split them yourself.

```
with open(Response, 'rU', encoding='utf-8') as data:
    separated = data.read().split('","')
    try:
        x = ElementTree.XML(separated[3])
        print(x)
        xml.etree.ElementTree.dump(x)
        y = ElementTree.XML(separated[4])
        xml.etree.ElementTree.dump(y)
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
```

outputs

```
<Element 'Request' at 0xb6d973b0>
<Request RequestType="FOO" TransactionID="3"><InstitutionISO /><CallID>23</CallID><MemberID>12</MemberID><MemberPassword /><RequestData><AccountNumber>2</AccountNumber><AccountSuffix>85</AccountSuffix><AccountType>S</AccountType><MPIAcctType>Checking</MPIAcctType><TransactionCount>10</TransactionCount></RequestData></Request>
<Response RequestType="HoldInquiry" TransactionID="2"><ShareList>0000',0001,0070,</ShareList></Response>
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I don't have control of how the CSV comes in but I am amazed that one can avoid csv reader altogether!

Comment: well, this is just what is says "comma,separated,values" :) and while csv reader should handle commas inside pretty well - it treats doublequotes literaly in Request, so eventually comma is not quoted, and thus You got multiple separate tokens after 0000'